# do effect on mouseleave but not if over a specific element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have mouseleave effect always EXCEPT if the cursor is over a certain element?

So say I have two divs called div1 and div2, I would get the `mouseleave` effect by doing:

```
$('div.div1').mouseleave(function() {
    alert('code');
});
```

Could I have the same effect UNLESS the cursor is over `div2` after the mouse moves away from `div1` ?

Comment: Hi check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5018955/2887133 I guess you want some like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.div1').not('div2').mouseleave(function() {
alert('code');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Think half of us misunderstood the question. +1 for @BrianGlaz.

Answer (score 17):

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HBCWs/

```
$( function() {
    $('.div1').mouseleave( function(e) {
        if( ! $(e.toElement).hasClass('div2') ) {
            alert( 'not div2!' );
        }
    });
});
```

You can use the `toElement` property of the jquery event object to check which element the mouse moved to after leaving `.div1`

Answer (score 3):

Might this thread be of help?

[Check what element the cursor is on upon mouseleave() with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761117/check-what-element-the-cursor-is-on-upon-mouseleave-with-jquery)

He seems to want to do something similar, and this was accepted as an answer:

> You need to use event.toElement || e.relatedTarget:
>
> $('li').mouseleave(function(e) {
>
> ```
> // new element is: e.toElement || e.relatedTarget
> ```
>
> });

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check below fiddle, when mouse leaves div1, an alert message is displayed, but when mouse leaves div2, event is not triggered.

http://jsfiddle.net/ACuE8/

```
$('div#div1').mouseleave(function() {
  alert("In div 1");
});
```